# Tapped event in TapGestureRecognizer is not raised up

Tags: c#, maui, .net-7.0

I want to show messages same as Whatsapp.Links and Phone Numer be clickable.Location and order of these is dynamic.by thanks ChatGPT i use this codes:

MessagePage.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiChatApp.ClientApp.Views.MessagePage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiChatApp.ClientApp.Utils"
             Title="MessagePage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:MessageToFormattedStringConverter x:Key="MessageToFormattedStringConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <CollectionView x:Name="contactsCollection"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Chats}"
                        Margin="20"
                        SelectionMode="None"
                        ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView"
        HeightRequest="500"
                       >

            <!-- Designate how the collection of items are laid out -->
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" ItemSpacing="10" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

            <!-- Define the appearance of each item in the list -->
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label FontSize="14">
                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                <Binding Converter="{StaticResource MessageToFormattedStringConverter}" Path="TextMessage" />
                            </Label.FormattedText>
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
        
</ContentPage>
```

MessageToFormattedStringConverter.cs

```
public class MessageToFormattedStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
        //    MessageViewModel vm = new ();
            if (value is string message && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            {


                #region NewCode
                FormattedString formattedMessage = new FormattedString();
                // Split message into words
                var words = message.Split(' ');
                bool isFirstIteration = true;
                foreach (var word in words)
                {
                    if (isFirstIteration)
                    {
                        isFirstIteration = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        formattedMessage.Spans.Add(new Span() { Text = " " });
                    }
                    if (IsUrl(word) || IsPhoneNumber(word))
                    {
                        // Create a span for the URL and set its properties
                        Span linkSpan = new Span()
                        {
                            Text = word,
                            TextColor = Colors.Blue,
                            TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline
                        };
                        var link_tap = new TapGestureRecognizer();
                        link_tap.NumberOfTapsRequired = 1;
                        link_tap.Tapped += async (s, e) =>
                        {
                            string url = string.Empty;

                            if (s is Label label && label.Text != null)
                            {
                                url = label.Text;
                            }
                            else if (s is Span span && span.Text != null)
                            {
                                url = span.Text;
                            }
                            if (Uri.TryCreate(message, UriKind.Absolute, out Uri uriResult)
                                                                            && (uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp || uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps))
                            {
                                await Launcher.OpenAsync(uriResult);
                            }
                            //}
                        };
                        linkSpan.GestureRecognizers.Add(link_tap);// new TapGestureRecognizer { Command = OpenLinkCommand, CommandParameter = word });
                        formattedMessage.Spans.Add(linkSpan);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Create a span for regular text
                        formattedMessage.Spans.Add(new Span() { Text = word });
                    }
                }
                return formattedMessage;
                #endregion
            //    return vm.CreateMessageWithLinks(message);
            }
            return new FormattedString();
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        private bool IsUrl(string word)
        {
            // Use a simple check or regex to verify if the word is a URL
            return Uri.TryCreate(word, UriKind.Absolute, out var uriResult) && (uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp || uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps);
        }
        public static bool IsPhoneNumber(string number)
        {
            return Regex.Match(number, @"^\+?(\d+\-?\d+)+$").Success;
        }
    }
```

all code is ok and show messages same as Whatsapp but when click on links is not raised tapped event.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Please look carefully,i create it for every links in loop iteration

Comment: `if (s is Label` - isn't `s` a `Span` in this context?

Comment: @Jason i put breakpoint in this line , it's never raised event.

Comment: I would try adding a Tapped recognizer to a simple span in XAML just to verify that its even possible

Comment: [open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4734). Thread has some confusion as to whether the fix on Windows was released or not. Try .Net 8 Preview build. Or wait for .Net 8 release.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve it's very bad for me to explain for my clients.

Comment: The consensus among app developers who use .Net is that Microsoft was premature in declaring Maui ready for production use in 2022. .Net 8 release is scheduled for [November 8](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-8-preview-7/). You could add a comment on that open issue, asking whether the fix will be available under .Net 7 Maui before that date.

Comment: See if [SyncFusion’s example](https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/create-a-hyperlink-ui-in-net-maui-preview-13.aspx) works. I doubt it will, since it also uses tap gesture recognizer. But perhaps they have used it slightly differently.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve i need make some span dynamically based on input text but in your ref is made one span.but i try it for testing